# Django app on Apache2 Forbidden 403 Response

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, wsgi

I have been battling with this for about an hour and I am not sure how to fix the issue. It seems my Apache server is running fine but anytime I try to access the website I get a Forbidden 403 Error.

**Here Is what added to the default .conf file**

```
<Directory "/home/mredwin/website\ v1.0/marketingvideosclub">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/mredwin/website\ v1.0/marketingvideosclub/wsgi.py"
WSGIDaemonProcess marketingvideosclub python-home="/home/mredwin/website\ v1.0/venv" python-path="/home/mredwin/website\ v1.0"
WSGIProcessGroup marketingvideosclub
```

And I checked the logs and there is nothing useful in there except that it is getting a GET and it is returning a 403 error code.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Have you set ALLOWED_HOSTS correctly in your settings?

Comment: Yes I have. I tested the application using the Django test server on my servers IP address before setting up apache and wsgi and it was working perfectly. @IainShelvington

Comment: Well, I just added <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory> and am getting a 404. so that is progress. After 4 hours...